# From stat_summary to geom_ function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to rewrite the plot down here using geom_ function rather that stat_summary. Any suggestions?

Thanks for the attention.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mpg)+
  stat_summary(
    mapping = aes(x = class, y = hwy),
    fun.ymin = min,
    fun.ymax = max,
    fun.y = median
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you want that? (Your code only needs ggplot2. There is no reason to install and load a giant meta package.)

Comment: What do you mean with "Your code only needs ggplot2"? I install it because I believe that mpg was a tidyverse database. Doesn't it? In anycase, it's a quest about how to use functions in ggplot. It asks to rewrite the code above using the geom_function associated to stat_summary.

Comment: So I can't draw the graph using a geom. Neither if I call  `geom_pointrange`. Right?

Comment: You are using a `geom`. The default is `geom_pointrange`, but you can easily change it. You always need a `geom` and a `stat` together to draw something in ggplot2.

Comment: Ok. Do you know how can I set `geom_pointrange` to draw the graph above? I upload it now.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain clearly. Consider this example: `ggplot(data=mpg) + geom_bar(mapping= aes(x= class))`. We know that geoms and stats are interchangeable. Right? So I can code: `ggplot(data=mpg) + stat_count(mapping= aes(x= class))` getting the same graph. In my case, it asks to do the same thing

Comment: Ok. But here the problem is: re-create the graph using geom instead of stat. Then I'm not worried about stat's default parameter cause I've started  from that.

Comment: Now I understand. Because it's a question of a test. Anyway thanks for all. You clarify the link between geoms and stats. To the next question.

Comment: I retract my comments and say the opposite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ggplot(data = mpg)+
  geom_pointrange(
    mapping = aes(x = class, y = hwy),
    fun.ymin = min, #passed to the stat via the ...
    fun.ymax = max, #ditto
    fun.y = median, #ditto
    stat = "summary"
  )
```

Comment: In the new version of ggplot2 use this code:
`ggplot(data = mpg)+
  geom_pointrange(
    mapping = aes(x = class, y = hwy),
    fun.min = min,
    fun.max = max, 
    fun = median, 
    stat = "summary"
  )`